# amazon ec2 and registered domain 1&1

Tags: amazon-ec2, domain

I have an instance running on Amazon EC2.  I need to point my domain `example.com` at 1und1 to this instance.  How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to run a nameserver on your instance instead of using Amazon's Route 53 offering? Or do you just want the domain to point to your instance IP?

Comment: yes I want my Ip to point to my instance ip. I have been trying to redirect cname but 1und1 refuse to accept the instance name because is too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with 1&1's interface, but it looks like you can set up [A records using their DNS service](http://help.1and1.com/domains-c36931/domain-administration-c79822/dns-settings-c37586/how-do-i-editchange-a-domains-ip-address-a-record-a599296.html). You should follow the instructions on their page to point your domain name to an IP address.

You can find out what your instance IP is in the Amazon EC2 console. Click on an instance name in the instances list. Directly below the name will be the public IP for that instance. I have attached a screenshot for clarity:

[image: EC2 instance selection]

In this example, the public IP address is 249.212.101.96. This is the IP address you should enter in Step 5 of the instructions on the 1&1 site.

Answer (score 0):

For 1&1, you need to go to your domain parameters on their website. Then go to **modify DNS parameters**, then go to **A / AAAA registration**, choose "another IP address" and in **Ipv4** or **Ipv6** write your IP from aws server (or create an **Elastic IP** in aws and use this one for **Ipv4**).